# Why does `\left|` insert unecessary vertical space below its argument?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

When using `\left|` and `\right|` to typeset absolute value, I get unnecessary space as follows

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    SDSCR_{i} = \frac{\left| V_{R, \thinspace i} \right|^{2}}{
    \left| S_{eq, \thinspace i}^{\adjustbox{raise=0.1\baselineskip}{*}} \right|
    \left| Z_{RR, \thinspace ii} \right|}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is because  delimiters are symmetric w.r.t. the math axis, and there is only a discrete set of sizes

Comment: Why do you raise the `*` superscript even higher? That the main cause...

Comment: @Werner For aesthetics because the variable would look crowded.

Comment: If `SDSCR` is an identifier/variable, it should not be typeset in math italic -- it looks awful that way

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. Most people here seem to not like italic math, but in electrical engineering, italic math for variables and even subscripts somtimes is the norm.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: Well, as long as don't have to read such articles ;-) One symbol in italic math is no problem, but using an abbreviation or term like SDSCR math italic is really wrong, in my point of view.

Comment: But if you use italic you should use `\mathit{SDSCR}_{i}`, without \mathit the spacing is all wrong.

Comment: you can use an italic font but use `\mathit{eq}` _never_ use the default math italic font for multi-letter names the whole design of the font is to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables not a word. compare `$diff+\mathit{diff}$`

Comment: the `*` looks far too high as it ism and as Werner says it is making the `| |` too large, Use `\bigl| S^*_{..}\bigr|`

Answer (score 2):

delimiters are centred on the math axis, so by making the `*` extra high you are forcing the delimiters to have extra depth, but it is usually better to use fixed size delimiter. Also never use the math italic font for multi-letter identifiers;

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}




\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mathit{SDSCR}_{i} = \frac{\bigl| V_{\mathit{f}R,  i} \bigr|^{2}}{
    \bigl| S_{\mathit{eq},  i}^{*} \bigr|
    \bigl| Z_{\mathit{RR},  ii} \bigr|}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```